# Group By include non-aggregate field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with duplicate values in `field2` and `field1` has values I want to preserve in a query.

```
field1  field2
 Bob       2
 Bob       2
 Bob       3
 Bob       3
```

This query uses a group by clause:

```
select field2
rom table
group by field2
```

As we all know I cannot include `field1` in the select. I need to include `field1` in my output. Not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to preserve from `field1`? The MIN value?

```
  select field2, min(field1) field1
    from table
group by field2
```

Perhaps the MAX value?

```
  select field2, max(field1) field1, count(field2) total
    from table
group by field2
```

You have to put an aggregate against it, otherwise it won't make sense.  Consider this data:

```
field1   field2
Bob      2
Jim      2
Tim      2
```

Okay, so you want `field1` with `field2`.  You group by `field2` to give you a single row with `field2` in the output.  You cannot have all 3 of (Bob,Jim,Tim) in the row, and that's the reason why you must put an aggregate against it to logically choose just one value (or an aggregate of several, such as an average of a numeric column).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

```
select * 
from table T
join
   (select field2
    from table
    group by field2)A
on T.field2=A.field2
```